# Access location services from Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an application in Unity, which uses GPS of the user's device.

But in order to test it, I have to build it to the device, since I can't access my MacBook Location services from Unity.

Is there any way to make the location services of my MacBook accessible from Unity?

Comment: Can you mock it? if in editor use value else use GPS location. You are not really moving with your mac so you can pass a default value.

Comment: You can access the GPS and other sensors on mobile devices from the Editor. See the duplicate for more info.